Looking for Sci-Fi book about boy leaving Earth and end up fishing for huge white manta ray on other world
This book starts with a boy and his brother on Earth at some point in the future. They explore an old abandoned smoke tower. I believe one falls and they’re almost caught by pirates.
Later in the book, the boys find work to get their parents off-world before Earth's air is not well to breathe and they get sent different times/places by going through portals.
The main character gets sent to some sort of ocean world where the main focus in fishing. He gets out with a crew and they go around harpoon creatures and whatnot day-in, day-out. They have to be careful to avoid the pirates. I know at one point the finally get the fabled big one, what I remember is a huge white stingray, that pulls the boat fast.
I also remember at some point the main character gets captured by pirates on this ocean world but manages to escape and I believe he also finds an island of like aged children.
I think at the end of the book the boy finds some place where there’s no struggle living? The fishing part was a big part of the book.
